# Javascript and PHP Regular Expression to exclude different chars

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I want to use the PHP function **preg_match** and the JS function ***test*** to exclude strings with this chars: |, +, --, =, <, >, !=, (, ), %, *

Can you give me the correct pattern for this expression ?

Now i use this solution:

```
    pattern = /[+|=|<|>|(|)|%|*]/;
    if( pattern.test(mystring) )        
    {
        alert(.....);   
    }
```

But it doesn't work if i use:

```
pattern = /[+|=|<|>|(|)|%|*|--|!=]/;
if( pattern.test(mystring) )        
{
 alert(....);
}
```

because it doesn't accept a singular **-** or *!*

Comment: Anytime you feel stuck with RegEx, head over to http://jsregex.com/ for some practice and for review check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirect=no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For JavaScript you want `/[+=<>()%*|]|\!=|-{2}/`, usage:

```
new RegExp(/[+=<>()%*|]|!=|-{2}/).test('this!=that');
```

And in PHP `'/[+=<>()%*|]|!=|-{2}/'`, usage:

```
preg_match('/[+=<>()%*|]|!=|-{2}/','this!=that');
```

There is no need to put `|` (or operator) in your `[]` (character class) unless you want to match that specific character - this is assumed. Also note that character classes cannot contain a sequence/series of characters; you'll need to break those out and use `|` to separate the phrases. Here is a breakdown of the regex:

- `/` - start delimiter
- `[+=<>()%*|]` - match any character in here (singular)
- `|` - matches either what is on the left (character class) or what is on the right (phrase)
- `!=` - match exactly != (phrase)
- `|` - again, matches either what is on the left (phrase) or on the right (phrase)
- `-{2}` - matches the hyphen exactly twice (phrase with a quantifier)
- `/` - end delimiter

From the high level, it can be interpreted as follows:

- `A|B|C`, either A or B or C match
- A is then `[D]` where any character `D` matches
- D is then `+=<>()%*|`
- B is then `!=`
- C is then `E{2}` or `EE` (identical because of the quantifier `{n}`).
- E is then `-`

---

Now with your variables and regex instantiation style:

JS:

```
var pattern = /[+=<>()%*|]|!=|-{2}/;
if( pattern.test(mystring) ) 
{
    console.log(...);
}
```

PHP:

```
$pattern = '/[+=<>()%*|]|!=|-{2}/';
if ( preg_match($pattern,$mystring) )
{
    var_dump(...);
}
```

*Bonus: Take a look at [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions) in regards to what characters need to be escaped and in what contexts - in your case, none of them, but still a handy reference!*

Comment: thank you very much! it works! but you forget that i want to exclude the char "|"  now this the solution thanks of your advice: pattern = /[+=<>()%*\|]|!=|-{2}/;

Comment: @GabrieleMandalari oops! I added `|` to the character class. No need to escape it with a `\ `. Only `^-]\ ` must be escaped inside `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need the `|` if you're using `[ ]` - the square brackets imply a match against any one of the characters inside.

To include the `-` just quote it with `\`:

```
var pattern = /[+=<>()%*\-!=|]/;
```

*edit* — I was overly hasty in reading your question. To deal with `!=` and `--`, those will have to be broken out into separate sub-patterns:

```
var pattern = /[+=<>()%*|]|(!=)|(--)/;
```

Comment: Just a moment! This pattern exclude a singular - or !. It's not correct for me

Comment: @GabrieleMandalari oh well sorry; I misunderstood. If you need to exclude multi-character patterns it has to be different. I will alter the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape special chars (for example, parenthesis) using backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is incorrect in both cases.  If you want to use a regular expression to test strings containing those characters just use `[+=<>()|&!*-]`.  This is how you write a character group--you don't put bars between each character.  If you want your group to contain `-`, always place that last (otherwise it might be confused as part of a character range like `a-z` or `0-9`).